# Install pre-installed packages

Tags: ubuntu-minimal, preinstallation

I have a minimal install of Ubuntu on my desktop, and I would like to move to a normal install of Ubuntu (install ubuntu pre-installed packages all at once).
Is it possible to install everything on a single command ? If not, can I have a full list of all the pre-installed packages ?
Thanks

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` should do the trick.

Comment: ... and if you want to install some other program packages you can do it with separate command lines  `sudo apt-get install program-package` with or many on the same command line for example `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop gimp htop ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: Installing ubuntu-desktops doesn't works, it just tells me it is already at the newest version...

Comment: Installing "program-package" returns that this package doesn't exists.

Comment: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --install-recommends` (yes your `ubuntu-desktop` was the latest, it was the recommended packages that were likely in the 'drop' list ... if this didn't achieve the result; I'd use `install --reinstall` to force re-install....